# what do classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/ mean in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[Spring boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) says:

> Config locations are searched in reverse order. By default, the configured locations are classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/. The resulting search order is:
>   1.file:./config/
>   2.file:./
>   3.classpath:/config/
>   4.classpath:/

In my opinion, `classpath:/` is the root directory of a `jar`, and `classpath:/config/` is the subdirectory of the root. But what do `file:./config/` and `file:./` mean? Where can I find out more detailed information about these online?

Comment: does not looked up the stuff. But file is just more specific then classpath.

Answer (score 0):

file:./ means current directory (.) and the slash after means you start in the current directory and go from there. but these start from the file system. so what ever file is making this reference it would start in that directory, irregardless of your classpath location.

classpath:/config/ would also mean to starts from the classpath root and looks for a config subfolder.

classpath:/ means start at the class path root.

the classpath root is typically the project folder you created the project in. eclipse or intelliJ or net beans set that stuff up for you pretty easily.